# Star Bright short story

Tags: short-stories, story-identification, powers

This is a short story about a super intelligent child named Star.

She has a friend almost as intelligent.

They discover a way to get to another dimension or universe where similarly gifted people have gone.

Her father hopes to find a way to follow them to protect her.

Comment: Is the *name* of this story "Star Bright"? Or is that merely a description?

Comment: It's one of my favorite stories; I originally read it in a compilation called 'The Mathematical Magpie.'  -- You are correct about the name; it is 'Star-Bright'.  See the linked question (with the Dup VTC) for details.

Comment: @K-H-W - We don't vote to close as dupes until the OP confirms that it's a dupe.

Comment: The exact title is ["Star, Bright"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56261) (note comma) and it's by [Mark Clifton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Clifton). At the Internet Archive you can read the [*Galaxy* text](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v04n04_1952-07#page/n5/mode/2up) or listen to the [*X Minus One* radio dramatization](https://archive.org/details/OTRR_X_Minus_One_Singles).

Comment: @Valorum -- Interesting; is that a recent change?  I don't see anything on Meta about it, nor in the [help files](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).  Did I miss a change?

Comment: @K-H-W - [Closing Story-Ident questions as duplicates (where there's no acceptance)](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/20774)

Comment: @Valorum In this case, the OP confirmed it's a dupe by closing it themselves!

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I noticed that :-) Still, the principle is that we don't close them even if it's really obvious.